# Multi-thread queue with sql server table and C# (.net core)

Tags: .net-core, queue, message-queue, priority-queue, conflict

I'm developing an engine for sending SMS message. All message are store in a database table. the engine should get a list of the 100 highest priority message from the queue and send it to the operator server and update the selected list status. the problem is when two thread want update the table at the same time and conflict. What is is the best way to create a thread-safe queue with highest throughput?

Comment: The highest throughput is -> SingleThread <-  Concurrency needs of locks, or any other kind of semaphoring. Which means poor performance. Take a look at what LMAX did to achieve the highest throughput on their engine, they've come up with a solution called disruptor: https://github.com/disruptor-net/Disruptor-net (Hint: its single threaded). Some other examples of high performance single thread is Redis, or Javascript.

Comment: Hi. Thanks for your reply. I used Output Cluase(http://rusanu.com/2010/03/26/using-tables-as-queues/) with multi thread. In my test there are not any problem.what do you think about Output Clause ?